# Removing 0 Vaules from Subgroups in R studio

Tags: r

Hello I am new to R and am trying to take out row with an `==0` value .

I really am new and might be making simple mistake but I can't seem to figure it out

This is what i've tried

```
Simplecount <- na.omit[,Simple$Counts >=1,]

object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
```

The data table below is called `Simple`

```
row.names   Time    INT Counts
19  234     13703   4   0
20  235     13803   4   0
21  236     13903   4   0
22  237     14104   5   1
23  238     14204   5   0
61  276     18403   6   0
62  277     18503   7   1
63  278     18604   7   0
64  279     18704   7   0
```

Comment: Using the right tags would improve your chances of getting an answer!

Comment: The code offered was trying to use "[" on a function `na.omit`. That was the source of the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a misplaced comma in your code.

Try:

```
> simple[simple$Counts >= 1, ]
   row.names  Time INT Counts
22       237 14104   5      1
62       277 18503   7      1
```

Or, in this particular case, even the following would work:

```
simple[as.logical(simple$Counts), ]
```

Comment: yes  that worked I first tried 

    counts <- Simple[(Simple$Counts <10 & Simple$Counts >0),]
    allcounts <- Simple[Simple$Counts >= 1, ]